# Does this 去 mean reduce?

Tags: meaning

Does this 去 mean reduce?
煤炭企业面临多方面的压力：
The coal industry faces many kinds pressure
（1） 去产能压力。
（1） reduce production capacity pressure

Comment: No, 去 in this context means " to remove"

Comment: bkrs：transitive use:(4) 除去; 去掉 [remove; wipe off]
去死肌, 杀三虫。 (5) 又如: 去绝根株(斩草除根); 去疾(除去疾病); 去皮; 去邪归正(去掉邪恶, 归于正道)(14) 抛弃, 舍弃 [throw away](21) 通"驱"。 驱逐 [drive out; expel]
＂现代汉语词典＂去（４）除去；除掉：～病｜～火｜～皮｜这句话～几个字就简洁了。

Answer (score 3):

去 in this context means " to remove".

去 never directly mean "to reduce". You thought it does, because logically thinking, you know 'if you **keep reducing** something, it will eventually be all gone (**removed**).'

Therefore you can say: "**keep reducing until all gone**" is one of the methods to **remove**(去). But 去 itself doesn't mean "to reduce"

*If you hang(吊) someone by the neck, you are  killing him. but 吊 (hang) itself doesn't mean " to kill"*.